# Regex Captures Everything After

Tags: regex

Currently on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and I'm using the below test string:

```
Sinkhole: Unknown, URLReputation: Risk unknown, URL: https://35.com/tail/123@#$%^, URLCategory: Unknown
```

What I'm trying to **achieve** using regex is to get a full match like below:

```
URL: https://35.com/tail/123@#$%^
```

The regex I'm using is detailed below:

```
URL:\s((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$
```

Unfortunately, the regex above is capturing anything after the URL which is not what I need.

I'm new to regex and understand the basics but missing that last piece.

Comment: what do you want to obtain exactly?

Comment: It seems like you're doing some validation as well, which we would require more details on to help you.  A simple `URL: ([^,]*),` would capture anything following `URL: ` to the next `,`, [e.g. here](https://regex101.com/r/syWRh3/1/) thought it seems your needs are more complex than this.

Comment: Use `URL:\s*(.*?),\s` and get Group 1 value. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L49jjc/1)

Comment: @Ass3mbler I'm trying to return the URL: and the actual url. As an example, URL: https://someurl.com/whateverelsehere.

Comment: @zzevannn what you suggested is exactly what I need. The original regex I had was something I found just googling but what you stated is all I need. Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!